# When does freebitco.in cash out?

Tags: websites

I found a web site where you can win bitcoins, freebitco.in. How do they work? Do they use [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) to mine for bitcoins on your client?

And when do you get the mBTC you win there?

Answer (score 1):

According to the website, if you click on "Auto Withdraw Enabled", you see:

"Payments are automatically sent every Monday to all accounts with a balance greater than 0.00005460 BTC".

For example, yesterday I received my most recent payment around 1 AM on Tuesday EST.  They send the BTC with a note saying:

[image]

They state that it can take a while to get the payment approved.  From my experience with the site, I find they are pretty reliable.  They basically only check to make sure you didn't try to cheat somehow with referral exploitation or programs trying to modify the gambling feature they have.